# How can I do to return places in distance order

Tags: php, ios, mysql, api, google-maps

I have a database full of places (lets say more than 50) with their address. And from an APP they send me their location and I have to return the places order by the ones that are closer to the location they send me. Do I have to do a Google Maps API call everytime, and for the 50, to know?. Or there is another way, with better performance.
Thank you

Comment: if you stored there latitude\longitude you can sort them

Comment: Store latitude & longtitude for your locations and [use spatial index to find the nearest one](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/how-to-best-implement-nearest-neighbour-search-in-mysql).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'll assume that your database is MySQL and that you have the latitude and longitude for the stored places.

You can do a Geospatial search using SQL queries. For example this one

```
set @orig_lat=122.4058;
set @orig_lon=37.7907;

SELECT *, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((@orig_lat - abs(dest.lat)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(@orig_lat * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(dest.lat) *  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((@orig_lon – dest.lon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance
FROM Places dest
ORDER BY distance;
```

That assumes that you have the lat and lon columns and will get the places  from the database and order them by distance.

Take a look to this presentation as reference andd to understand the calculations http://es.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

Comment: link only answers are discouraged

Comment: Thanks for noticing it. I updated the response and added the link as reference only.